# R function - choose specific argument

Tags: r, function

Was trying to figure out how to make this function work:

```
test_function <- function(option = c(x,y,z)) {
    x <- 5
    y <- 50
    z <- 500
    y <- option + 1000
    return(y)
}
```

So I want to enter either x, y or z and to get the results based on the arguments that are store inside the function. For example:

```
 test_function(z) 
 [1] 1500         ##option = z = 500; y = 500 + 1000
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
test_function <- function(option) {

  case <- switch(option, "x" = 5, "y" = 50, "z" = 500)
  y <- case + 1000
  return(y)
}
```

Notice that the argument should be a character

```
> test_function("z")
[1] 1500
```

Comment: To ensure that option is one of those values, you can use an unnamed arg to `switch`, like `switch(option, x = 5, y = 50, z = 500, stop("Invalid value."))`

Answer (score 3):

```
f0 = function(opt = c("x","y","z")) 
  c(x = 5, y = 50, z = 500)[[match.arg(opt)]] + 1000

f = function(opt_raw) f0( as.character(substitute(opt_raw)) )
```

Usage:

```
> f(x)
[1] 1005
> f(y)
[1] 1050
> f(z)
[1] 1500
```

Probably better to stick with `f0` rather than insisting on passing `x` without quotes.